# Nested Spinner Android Design Issues ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I'm working with spinner for the first time, and I don't understand why the second spinner doesn't look exactly like the first one even though they were created practically the same (the only difference is the data). These are nested.

The design implemented it with "constraint layout"

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spCategorie"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/categorieText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categorieText"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Categorie:"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spProduct"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/productText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spCategorie" />
```

[This is how it looks in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFmxJ.png)

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, productsCat);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    categorie.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    categorie.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnersEvents());
    product.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnersEvents());

private class SpinnersEvents implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (parent.getId() == R.id.spCategorie){
            String[] productsName = getProductName(productsCat[position]);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterChild = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, productsName);
            arrayAdapterChild.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            product.setAdapter(arrayAdapterChild);
        }else{
            price.setText(String.valueOf(tempList.get(position).getPrice()));
            imgPrd.setImageResource(tempList.get(position).getImage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your code may help you, you can also set wrapcontent in spinner or increase the size to view text proper

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/categorieText"
                android:layout_width="73dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Categorie:"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spCategorie"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/categorieText"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productText"
                android:layout_width="73dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Product:"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/categorieText"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spproduct"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spCategorie"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/categorieText"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in the code, not in the layout.

The second spinner must be:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterChild = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, productsName);
```

instead:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterChild = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, productsName);
```

In this case, calling the getBaseContext() method generated that particular problem.

Sorry for the confusion.